# 'Wierd' .insertAfter() behavior

Tags: jquery, arrays, each, insertafter

I'm trying to inject some elements between my paragraphs... - but it's not quite working as inteended:

What I would like to see is something like this:

```
<p>Text1.</p>
    <span>test1</span> <--injected element
<p>Text2.</p>
    <span>test2</span> <--injected element
<p>Text3.</p>
    <span>test3</span> <--injected element
<p>Text4.</p>
    <span>test4</span> <--injected element
    <span>test5</span> <--injected element
    <span>test6</span> <--injected element
```

But the result looks a little different:

```
<p>Text1.</p>
<span>test6test5test4test3test2test1</span>
<p>Text2.</p>
<span>test6test5test4test3test2test1</span>
<p>Text3.</p>
<span>test6test5test4test3test2test1</span>
<p>Text4.</p>
<span>test6test5test4test3test2test1</span>
```

My code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
            var xArray = 
            [
                "test0",
                "test1",
                "test2",
                "test3",
                "test4"
            ];
            $.each(xArray, function (index, value) {
                $("<span>" + value + "<span>").insertAfter(".articleText p");
            }); 
        });
```

What to do/change...?

Answer (score 3):

```
        var $paragraphs = $(".articleText p");

        $.each(xArray, function (index, value) {
            $("<span>" + value + "<span>").insertAfter($paragraphs.eq(index));
        });
```

You are inserting the element after ALL `p` tags instead of the specific one you want.  You can use `eq` to select the correct `p` element.

You will also have to deal with the case of having more elements in your array than you have `p` elements.

Comment: One thing missing from the OP's question is what to do if there is no <p> tag at some index, for example, the logic to place span test5 and span test6 in the question.

Comment: >the logic to place span test5 and span test6 in the question
---
True - the scripts works perfect, except that the leftover spans (5,6) ain't beeing displayed... - how would that do...? :)